# Keep the same order of ids in a request and the response ef core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using ef core and I have a get method

```
public async Task<StudentEntity[]> GetStudents(GetStudentsRequest request)
    {

        var students = await _context.Students
            .Where(student => request.StudentIds.Contains(student.Id))
            .ToArrayAsync();

        //map here to the student entity
        studentsEntity = students.Select(x=> new StudentEntity(..bla bla bla ))

        return studentsEntity;
    }
```

with the request

```
public class GetStudentsRequest 
{
    public int[] StudentIds{ get; }

    public GetStudentsRequest (int[] studentIds)
    {
        StudentIds = studentIds;
    }
}
```

The problem is I want in each order of the ids of the request I want to keep the same order in the result

For example request: [11,7,2,9]
I want to get the result in the same order

```
{
studentId :11,
Name: Nick
},
{
studentId :7,
Name: Anna
},
{
studentId :2,
Name: Helene
}
,
{
studentId :9,
Name: Jason
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that? If the `studentId` is unique than you can easily pick any of the `StudentEntity` by `FirstOrDefault` from the `studentsEntity`

Comment: @PeterCsala i want a list of ids as request and then i want to return the entities in the same order

Comment: I understand your requirement but why do you need that? What is the use case that requires this ordering?

Comment: @PeterCsala it is a business requirement

Comment: This has nothing to do with EF Core, since you are processing the already materialized result set in memory (with either LINQ to Objects or BCL methods), so removing the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enumerable.Select` has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) with selector with two parameters - the second one represents the index of the source element. You can use it to create a dictionary containing mapping from id to original index and use it to order. Something like that (assuming `StudentEntity` has `studentId` field):

```
public async Task<StudentEntity[]> GetStudents(GetStudentsRequest request)
{
    var students = await _context.Students
        .Where(student => request.StudentIds.Contains(student.Id))
        .ToArrayAsync();
     var orderer = request.StudentIds
        .Distinct()
        .Select((id, index) => (id,  index))
        .ToDictionary(t => t.id, t => t.index);
    //map here to the student entity
    studentsEntity = students.Select(x=> new StudentEntity(..bla bla bla ))
             .OrderBy(s => orderer[s.studentId])
             .ToArray();      


    return studentsEntity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you join from the id collection to the student entity collection the order of the first collection is preserved.

```
return
  from id in request.StudentIds
  join s in studentsEntity on id equals s.studentId
  select s
```

Comment: With proper syntax, this is indeed a better option than the redundant mapping and ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
var students = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new Student
{
    Id = i,
    Name = $"Student_{i}"
});

int[] ids = new[] { 8, 3, 2, 1, 4 };

var result =ids.Select(id=>students.First(f=>f.Id==id));


foreach (var student in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{student.Id} - {student.Name}");
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `List` would iterate on the collection in the order of the indexer i.e. from 0 to n-1, you could use the `ForEach` over `request.StudentIds` to prepare the response in the same order.

```
.
.
.
var studentEntity = new List<StudentEntity>();
 request.StudentIds.ForEach(id =>
 { 
    var student = students.First(s => s.Id == id);
    studentEntity.Add(new StudentEntity(..bla bla bla ));
 });

return studentEntity;
```